# Filter plugging from co2 pressure

Tags: kegging

I have been fermenting in a 42 Blichmann and when transferring the beer I plug the 1 micron filter with yeast even though I have 
dumped most of trub and yeast during the 3 weeks of fermenting.  I use 5 lbs pressure from the co2 tank.  I did not have this problem when siphoning from a secondary carboy.  Does the pressure stir up the yeast?
The outlet is well above the settled yeast.

Answer (score 1):

If the beer is cloudy to the eye a 1 micron filter will clog very quickly.

The beer must not have completed fining before filtering.

In the future pull a sample before starting to filter to make sure it's completely crashed out first.